# Postgres Join with LIKE

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-8.4, postgresql-9.0

In PostgreSQL I have a table

```
tbl1
id -- RCODE -- COUNTRY --
1     US/MSR   United states of America
2     GY/LSR   Germany
3     CA/FSA   Canada

tbl2
id -- Name -- CCODE
33    T1      US        
44    Y1      CA       
55    W1      GY
```

**can the tables be joined with LIKE condition on fields  RCODE on tbl1 with  CCODE on tbl2 ?**  such that
i gets  the result as

```
id --NAME-- RCODE -- CCODE--- COUNTRY
```

i shall provide the id of tbl2 ie) when i give the id 44
the result will be

```
id --NAME-- RCODE -- CCODE--- COUNTRY
44   Y1     CA/FSA   CA       Canada
```

can any one help me to solve this query , it is PostgreSQL

***one thing is that  first two char in RCODE is same to that of CCODE in table2.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select tbl2.name, tbl1.rcode, tbl2.ccode, tbl1.country
from tbl1 
  join tbl2 on substring(tbl1.rcode, 1, 2) = tbl2.ccode
```

Comment: @cc4re then consider upvoting and marking the answer as the correct one :)

Comment: If you need a smart and small index, use the same expression: CREATE INDEX smart_ids ON tbl1 (substring(tbl1.rcode, 1, 2));

Comment: In PostgreSQL 9.1 or later you can use the simpler [`left()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) for the purpose: `JOIN tbl2 ON left(tbl1.rcode, 2) = tbl2.ccode`.

Comment: is it possible to do with LIKE and wildcard %

Comment: @cc4re: sure, just put it into the `ON` condition.

Answer (score 1):

For a similar problem, I used something like:

```
select
tbl2.id as id,
tbl2.name as NAME,
tbl1.rcode as RCODE,
tbl1.ccode as CCODE,
tbl1.country as COUNTRY
from tbl1, tbl2
where substring(tbl1.rcode, 1, 2) = tbl2.ccode;
```

The numbers in the substring expression are the 1 based index of the first character of the substring, and the length of the substring.

Other string operators, such as trim(), lower(), and upper() can also be useful.  A more complete list of available string operators is at:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html